Compiling Qt 5.15.15: error: 'XKB_KEY_dead_lowline' was not declared in this scope
I am trying to compile Qt 5.15.15 from scratch because Qt now requires you to create an account in their website.
I've run:
mkdir build
cd build
../configure
gmake

I am getting the following error:
/home/aitor/Baixades/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.15/qtbase/src/platformsupport/input/xkbcommon/qxkbcommon.cpp:276:16: error: ‘XKB_KEY_dead_lowline’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘XKB_KEY_dead_belowring’?
  276 |         Xkb2Qt<XKB_KEY_dead_lowline,            Qt::Key_Dead_Lowline>,
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                XKB_KEY_dead_belowring
/home/aitor/Baixades/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.15/qtbase/src/platformsupport/input/xkbcommon/qxkbcommon.cpp:276:69: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  276 |         Xkb2Qt<XKB_KEY_dead_lowline,            Qt::Key_Dead_Lowline>,
      |                                                                     ^
/home/aitor/Baixades/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.15/qtbase/src/platformsupport/input/xkbcommon/qxkbcommon.cpp:277:16: error: ‘XKB_KEY_dead_aboveverticalline’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘XKB_KEY_dead_abovering’?
  277 |         Xkb2Qt<XKB_KEY_dead_aboveverticalline,  Qt::Key_Dead_Aboveverticalline>,
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                XKB_KEY_dead_abovering
/home/aitor/Baixades/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.15/qtbase/src/platformsupport/input/xkbcommon/qxkbcommon.cpp:277:79: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  277 |         Xkb2Qt<XKB_KEY_dead_aboveverticalline,  Qt::Key_Dead_Aboveverticalline>,
      |                                                                               ^
/home/aitor/Baixades/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.15/qtbase/src/platformsupport/input/xkbcommon/qxkbcommon.cpp:278:16: error: ‘XKB_KEY_dead_belowverticalline’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘XKB_KEY_dead_belowtilde’?
  278 |         Xkb2Qt<XKB_KEY_dead_belowverticalline,  Qt::Key_Dead_Belowverticalline>,
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                XKB_KEY_dead_belowtilde
/home/aitor/Baixades/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.15/qtbase/src/platformsupport/input/xkbcommon/qxkbcommon.cpp:278:79: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  278 |         Xkb2Qt<XKB_KEY_dead_belowverticalline,  Qt::Key_Dead_Belowverticalline>,
      |                                                                               ^
/home/aitor/Baixades/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.15/qtbase/src/platformsupport/input/xkbcommon/qxkbcommon.cpp:279:16: error: ‘XKB_KEY_dead_longsolidusoverlay’ was not declared in this scope
  279 |         Xkb2Qt<XKB_KEY_dead_longsolidusoverlay, Qt::Key_Dead_Longsolidusoverlay>,
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/aitor/Baixades/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.15/qtbase/src/platformsupport/input/xkbcommon/qxkbcommon.cpp:279:80: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  279 |         Xkb2Qt<XKB_KEY_dead_longsolidusoverlay, Qt::Key_Dead_Longsolidusoverlay>,
      |                                                                                ^
/home/aitor/Baixades/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.15/qtbase/src/platformsupport/input/xkbcommon/qxkbcommon.cpp:427:5: error: template argument 156 is invalid
  427 |     >::Data{}
      |     ^
/home/aitor/Baixades/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.15/qtbase/src/platformsupport/input/xkbcommon/qxkbcommon.cpp:427:5: error: template argument 157 is invalid
/home/aitor/Baixades/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.15/qtbase/src/platformsupport/input/xkbcommon/qxkbcommon.cpp:427:5: error: template argument 158 is invalid
/home/aitor/Baixades/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.15/qtbase/src/platformsupport/input/xkbcommon/qxkbcommon.cpp:427:5: error: template argument 159 is invalid
gmake[5]: *** [Makefile:759 : .obj/qxkbcommon.o] Erreur 1

I've not modified any code of course

There is a bug report: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-117950 which says it was fixed in Qt-5.15.16 with this change: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/commit/?id=8af35d27e8f02bbb99aef4ac495ed406e50e3cca

Getting this in 5.15.16: https://pastebin.com/MDvE6u5r
